# ScriptDB auto numbering

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a database like this one:

```
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();

var ob = {
    type: "employee",
    employee_id: 1,
    name: {
        first: "Fatima", 
        initial: "S", 
        last: "Pauli"
    },
    address: {
        street: "4076 Washington Avenue",
        city: "Jackson", state: "MS", zip: "39201"
    },
    department_id: 52
};

var stored = db.save(ob);
```

Now I want the `employee_id` to have auto-increment without looping trough the entire existing database.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to store a current max value of `employee_id` in a separate `ScriptDB` object and use the [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_lockservice) to provide atomicity, as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#atomicity_and_transactions), during reading and incrementing operations.

Comment: Why I did not think of that I don't know.... Why should I use the lock service ??

Comment: Because if you don't lock, multiple instances of your script may run simultaneously and you end up using the same number for two or more entries.